# Skew matrix in Android

Tags: android, matrix, view, android-canvas

I'm working on Android project. and I'm using View class to drawing bitmap using canvas with matrix.

How can I skew matrix? to be like this:

[image]

I'm using this code, but it is not working:

```
float[] src=new float[]{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0};
float[] dst=new float[]{0.2f,0,0,1,1,1,0.8f,0};
Paint paint = new Paint();
matrix.reset();     
matrix.postTranslate(-width / 2.0f, -height / 2.0f);        
matrix.postRotate(0/*(float)(angle*180/Math.PI) ,-width / 2.0f + 50, -height / 2.0f +50*/);
matrix.postScale(scale, scale); 
matrix.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, 4);
matrix.postTranslate(position.getX(), position.getY());             
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
canvas.concat(matrix);
```

Comment: Matrix.setPolyToPoly

Comment: thanks for your reply, but could you explain the method and it parameters in simple example as answer ?

Comment: use src as 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0 and dst 0.2,0,0,1,1,1,0.8,0 for example

Comment: Please look to above code, where is the wrong ?

Comment: see my answer below with a working code

Comment: In case anybody super cares, the problem with the setPolytoPoly command it does a set command. Those post- pre- concat that matrix with the current matrix and were fine but, the set command overwrites those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this:

```
class V extends View {

    private Bitmap b;
    private Matrix m;

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.layer0);
        m = new Matrix();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        int bw = b.getWidth();
        int bh = b.getHeight();
        float[] src = {0, 0, 0, bh, bw, bh, bw, 0};
        int DX = 100;
        float[] dst = {0 + DX, 0, 0, h, w, h, w - DX, 0};
        m.setPolyToPoly(src, 0, dst, 0, 4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(b, m, null);
    }
}
```

UPDATE to keep the image aspect ratio:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        int bw = b.getWidth();
        int bh = b.getHeight();
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, bw, bh);
        RectF dst = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        m.setRectToRect(src, dst, ScaleToFit.CENTER);

        float[] pts = {0, 0, 0, bh, bw, bh, bw, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        m.mapPoints(pts, 8, pts, 0, 4);
        int DX = 40;
        pts[8] += DX;
        pts[14] -= DX;
        m.setPolyToPoly(pts, 0, pts, 8, 4);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot pskink, I'll test it tomorrow because I don't have device now, I'll tell you what is the results.

Comment: see the UPDATE to keep the image aspect ratio